# V-Model not binding with the mask jquery

Tags: vue.js, mask

I am using form with v-model for phone input with mask library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<input type="text" v-model="phone" placeholder="телефон" class="form-control" id="phone">
```

when the vue created all fields set with mask

```
created: function () {
    var options =  {
        onComplete: function(e) {
            var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
            event.initEvent('input', true, true);
            e.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
            $("#phone").trigger('change');
        }
    };
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#phone").mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", options);
    });
```

I know that jquery and vue have different events handling so I've generated in options onComplete event handing which fire HTML event. It's does not working, what's wrong?

Comment: Take another look at the life cycle events of a vue instance, and you'll find that you're using the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

As @EricGuan alluded to, your script will not work in the `created` [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks), as the component is unaware of the template until after the `created` hook has fired.

Instead, use the `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```
mounted: function() {
  // your code here
}
```

[Working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWZxNp?editors=1111)